# Is it true that E [ X | E [ X | Y] ] = Ex [ X | Y] ? Does this law have a name?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables (say real numbers, or vectors in some vector space). It seems to me that the following is true:

E [ X | E [ X | Y ] ] = E [ X | Y]

Note that E [ X | Y ] is a random variable in it's own right. Also note that equality here is point-wise, for every point in the sample space of the joint distribution on on $(X,Y)$. My question, assuming I'm not missing something and the above is true, is whether this law has a name, or is written down / proved somewhere.

Comment: This is an extremely important result. I failed a course in probability because I couldn't correctly apply it. I think this is called Bayes' rule for expectation something but there is a name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z=E[X\ | \ Y]$. Your equation states: $E[X \ | \ Z]=Z$. This follows from the following fact.

**Tower Property of Conditional Expectation:**

$$E[E[X\ | \ \mathcal{F}]\ | \ \mathcal{G}]=E[X\ | \ \mathcal{G}],\text{ whenever }\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}.$$

**Proof of your equation:**

We apply the tower property with $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(Z)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(Y)$. Note that $\sigma(Z)\subset \sigma(Y)$ follows from the construction of $Z$ as a conditional expectation w.r.t. $Y$.

Plugging in to the tower property,
$$
\begin{align*}
E[E[X\ | \ \sigma(Y)]\ | \ \sigma(Z)]&=E[X\ | \ \sigma(Z)]\\
\implies E[Z\ | \ Z]&=E[X\ | \ Z]\\
\implies Z&=E[X\ | \ Z].
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What is $\sigma$ here?

Comment: It's a technical formality that means "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable". In general, conditional expectation is defined w.r.t. a $\sigma$-algebra, like $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{G}$. See the formal definition on the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

Comment: Ah, yes of course. That's an elegant proof, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Essentially the [law of iterated expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), perhaps more commonly written like $$\operatorname{E_X} [X] = \operatorname{E}_Y [ \operatorname{E}_{X \mid Y} [ X \mid Y]].$$

For a discrete case, the essence of the proof is 
$$\operatorname{E}_Y [ \operatorname{E}_{X \mid Y} [ X \mid Y]] = \sum_y \sum_x x \cdot \operatorname{P}(X=x \mid Y=y) \cdot \operatorname{P}(Y=y) =\sum_x x \cdot \operatorname{P}(X=x) =\operatorname{E_X} [X].$$

Comment: Can you actually flesh out why the OP's equation is equivalent to the equation you have written down?

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure I see the equivalence either...

Comment: What's with the subscripts?

Comment: I have read the question's $E [ X | E [ X | Y ] ]$ as $E_Y [ X | E [ X | Y ] ]$.  If you read it as  $E_{X|Y} [ X | E [ X | Y ] ]$  then it is trivial.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen: In the discrete case, $E_Y[Z(Y)] = \displaystyle \sum_y Z(y)P(Y=y)$ with the natural extension to general proability measure

Comment: But what's the significance of the subscript, i.e. why not just write $E[Z(Y)]$ as is commonly done?

Comment: @Stefan Hansen: My reading of what pre-kidney has done is essentially that given $Z=\operatorname{E}[X|Y]=z$ then $z=\operatorname{E}[X|Y]$.  This is why I have  $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{E} [ \operatorname{E} [ X \mid Y]] = $ while pre-kidney has $\operatorname{E} [ \operatorname{E} [ X \mid Y]] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]$

Comment: ?? E[X]=E[E[X∣Y]] is always true, E[E[X∣Y]]=E[X∣Y] rarely holds (and was used/proved/mentioned by nobody on the page).